# Como faço para utilizar o parseFloat nesse algoritmo ?

Tags: javascript, aplicação-web, front-end, programação-estruturada

Eu criei um algoritmo que receba a nota de 4 bimestre , que faça um calculo da média e mostre o resultado da aprovação .  Para o resultado da aprovação eu fiz da seguinte maneira .

Resultado da Aprovação  :

Aprovação com nota máxima = 10 .
Aprovação acima da média = 8 até 9 . 
Aprovação na média = 7 .
Recuperação = 6 . 
Reprovação  = 1 até 5 .

Problema =  Se o usuário  inserir o valor 7 em cada nota a média ficará 7 e irá mostrar " Aprovação na média = 7 " Porém , se inserir o valor de 7.3 em cada nota irá mostrar a seguinte mensagem " Reprovado " no caso era para mostrar " Aprovação acima da média ".

Obs ( Eu sei que  tenho que transformar alguma coisa para  ParseFloat  porém não estou sabendo onde  inserir o mesmo . )

```js
var s1 = prompt ( " Insira a nota do 1 Bimestre : ") ; 
var s2 = prompt ( " Insira a nota do 2 Bimestre : " ) ; 
var s3 = prompt ( " Insira a nota do 3 Bimestre : " ) ; 
var s4 = prompt ( " Insira a nota do 4 Bimestre : " ) ;


var s1 = Number (s1) ; 
var s2 = Number (s2) ; 
var s3 = Number (s3) ; 
var s4 = Number (s4) ; 

var media = parseFloat (( s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 ) / 4 ); 

if (media ==10)
{
 alert ( "Aprovação com nota maxima! " ) ; 
}  

else if ((media == 8) || ( media == 9 ) )
{
 alert ( " Aprovação acima da  média ! " ) ; 
} 

else if (media == 7) 
{
 alert ( " Aprovação com nota na média! " ) ; 
}

else if ( media == 6 ) 
{
 alert ( "Recuperação ! " ) ; 
}

else 
{
 alert ( " Reprovado ! " ) ; 
}
```

Comment: A resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

O problema é que nos seus `ifs` você não está cobrindo os valores entre as notas (como por exemplo 7.3). Modificando as verificações para o código seguinte sua lógica deve atender ao esperado:

```
if (media ==10) {
  alert ( "Aprovação com nota maxima! " ) ;
} else if ( media > 7) {
  alert ( " Aprovação acima da  média ! " ) ;
} else if (media == 7) {
  alert ( " Aprovação com nota na média! " ) ;
} else if ( media == 6 ) {
  alert ( "Recuperação ! " ) ;
} else {
  alert ( " Reprovado ! " ) ;
}
```

Comment: Já achei o erro . No lugar do "  if (media == 7) " deveria colocar    " else if ((media  > 7) && ( media < 10 ) ) ". Sendo assim , qualquer média que seja maior que 7 e menor que 10 irá aparecer a mensagem correta .

Answer (score 0):

Deve ficar desse modo para o funcionamento, o `parseFloat` vai diretamente na variável:

```js
var s1 = prompt("Insira a nota do 1 Bimestre: "); 
var s2 = prompt("Insira a nota do 2 Bimestre: "); 
var s3 = prompt("Insira a nota do 3 Bimestre: "); 
var s4 = prompt("Insira a nota do 4 Bimestre: ");

var s1 = parseFloat(s1); 
var s2 = parseFloat(s2); 
var s3 = parseFloat(s3); 
var s4 = parseFloat(s4); 

var media = (( s1 + s2 + s3 + s4 ) / 4 );

if(media == 10){

   alert("Aprovação com nota maxima!");

}else if (media > 7) {

   alert("Aprovação acima da média !");

} else if(media == 7) {

   alert(" Aprovação com nota na média!");

} else if( media == 6 ) {

   alert("Recuperação!");

} else{

   alert("Reprovado!");

}
```